# How to remove orientation from jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery

**This is my jQuery code**

```
<input type="text" name="assign_date" readonly class="form-control datepickermin" id="assign_date" required>
```

```js
$('.datepickermin').datepicker({
  orientation: "auto",
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  forceParse: false,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: new Date('2020-2-12'),
  endDate: new Date('2020-2-15'),
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
});
```

**This is Image**

[image: enter link description here]

**How to remove orientation from jQuery datepicker?**

```
             <option value="Pending" data-status="Pending" data-id ="'.$q->id.'"';
             if($q->status == 'Pending'): $return .= 'selected'; endif; $return .='>Pending</option>
             <option value="Completed" data-status="Completed" data-id ="'.$q->id.'"';
             if($q->status == 'Completed'): $return .= 'selected'; endif; $return .='>Completed</option>
             <option value="Hold" data-status="Hold" data-id ="'.$q->id.'"';
             if($q->status == 'Hold'): $return .= 'selected'; endif; $return .='>Hold</option>
             <option value="Prospect" data-status="Prospect" data-id ="'.$q->id.'"';
             if($q->status == 'Prospect'): $return .= 'selected'; endif; $return .='>Prospect</option>
```

Comment: Remove the `orientation` property? The problem and goal is not clear.

Comment: if you want to remove icon, then you can do this with css, `.datetimepicker:before, .datetimepicker:after {
    display: none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
.datetimepicker:before, .datetimepicker:after { display: none;}
```